# Emacs not asking for password for .gpg file

Tags: gpg, emacs24

Have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 which required an emacs reinstall of version 24

Now I've noticed that my symmetrically encrypted org mode file (file.org.gpg) no longer requires me to enter the pwd when opening.

Clearly its caching it somewhere now, but where and for how long?

Every now and then, it will prompt for pwd

I don't really want this behaviour, would rather enter pwd every time

I've checked `epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption` and its set to `nil`

Have also taken a look in `~/.gnupg` but therese no `gpg-agent.conf` file in there

So don't really have a clue where that pwd is being cached and how you can control that caching